# How to display same app users on top of contacts table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

In my Swift-app, when the users go to add friends, I want to display the same-app users on top of the table view and then the non-app users next to that.

I've the array of same app users in my Parse and I can get it.

But I don't know how to sort that out in table view?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort the names in your array and then pass those sorted names to tableview Delegate method. There is no option in tableview to sort itself. To sort array of strings, you can use sorting methods available in iOS.